# php get grouped values in Regex

Tags: php, regex

i am using php Regular expressions but i can't retrieve values that i group using `()`

this is my input 
`<img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" title="title" />`
i need only src value , this is my regex `'"<img src=\"(.*?)\".*?\/>"'`

if i can retrieve First group just like java patterns my problem is sloved

```
preg_match_all('"<img src=\"(.*?)\".*?\/>"', $source, $re);
print_r($re);
```

and it return full image tag like this `<img src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" title="title" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a single string, `preg_match` function is enough. You don't need to go for `preg_matchall` function. If you want to match more number of strings then you could use `preg_matchall` function. And also first try to match the exact string through the pattern rather than to go for grouping. If it's impossible to match a particular string then go for grouping.

In the below, matching the exact value of `src` attribute is done.

You could get the value of `src` in two ways,

### 1. positive lookbehind

**Regex:**

```
(?<=src=\")[^\"]*
```

**PHP code:(Through `match_all`)**

```
<?php
$string = "<img src=\"http://www.example.com/image.jpg\" title=\"title\" />";
$regex =  '~(?<=src=\")[^\"]*~';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

**PHP code:(Through `match`)**

```
<?php
$string = "<img src=\"http://www.example.com/image.jpg\" title=\"title\" />";
$regex =  '~(?<=src=\")[^\"]*~';
if (preg_match($regex, $string, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?> //=> http://www.example.com/image.jpg
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=src=\")` Positive look-behind is used here. So the regex engine puts the match marker just after to the `src="`.
- `[^\"]*` Now it starts matching any character zero or more times but not of `"`. When it finds a `"`, it stops matching characters.

### 2. Using `\K`

**Regex:**

```
src=\"\K[^\"]*
```

**PHP code (through `match`)**

```
<?php
$string = "<img src=\"http://www.example.com/image.jpg\" title=\"title\" />";
$regex =  '~src=\"\K[^\"]*~';
if (preg_match($regex, $string, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?>  //=> http://www.example.com/image.jpg
```

**Explanation:**

- `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match.
- `src=\"\K` So it discards the previously matched `src="`.
- `[^\"]*` Matches any character zero or more times but not of `"`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `preg_match_all` so that you need to pass index as well, use `print_r($re[1]);` to get results.

Answer (score 0):

I Got It Accidently !
we can Code Like this for first Grouped

```
print_r($re[1]);
```

Comment: We can also look into the manual? [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all)